# Convert a circular tube into an oval tube

Tags: modifiers

Like all newbies I'm probably asking something that has already been answered but here goes.
I've succeeded in building a circular tube 325 mm high and 214 mm external diameter with wall thickness of 4 mm.
I now need to make this tube oval but not a real oval more like a running track with half circles at each end and in my case with straight sides of 50 mm joining the two halves of the circle [image: oval not to scale]
Thanks in advance
Keith

Comment: This is easy to achieve with bezier curve objects and a bevel object

Comment: I'm really curious which interpretation is correct. I could be horribly wrong ( :

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't really know your topology, I better start from scratch. If I interpret your question right, here's how I would approach it:

I assume a Blender unit to be 1 meter. I don't use metrics, so you might have to adapt your values.

Create a cirle. In the redo panel to the left, enter the desired resolution (I chose 64) and as radius, enter .214/2

[image]

Go into Edit Mode with <kbd>TAB</kbd>, hit <kbd>A</kbd> to clear the selection and use <kbd>B</kbd> to select half of it (you could do a negative border select with <kbd>MMB</kbd>and spare the <kbd>A</kbd>).

Then press <kbd>Y</kbd>.

It's called split and will duplicate the verts at the border of your selection. In this case it means you now have two half circles. One is selected, one isn't.

[image]

With the right half still selected, move the right circle to the right with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> .05 <kbd>RETURN</kbd>, right?

Select all with <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and fill it with <kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

Inset the face with <kbd>I</kbd> .004 <kbd>RETURN</kbd>

[image]

Delete the inner face using <kbd>X</kbd>, "Only Faces"

[image]

Go into front view, select all and extrude up with <kbd>E</kbd> .325 <kbd>RETURN</kbd>
[image]

The finished tube with, I hope, the right dimensions.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Whatever the numbers, you might just do this[image]